# Datatex - Period Closure Ended with Info [Error]

Tags: erp

We are using Datatex NOW and while running period closure, it ends with below message `Closing base unit cost not valuated on stock transaction with key [ST Key].`
What could be the possible reason of this error and how this should be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This error arises due to multiple reasons, such as an incorrect MRN Transaction date with mismatched QCA – QFS – QCR transactions.
Following steps needs to be taken for MRN deletion with **extreme caution** and it requires Deletion privileges and will remove all documents related to your MRN and you will need to recreate these documents.

1. Note Purchase Order number against the entry appearing in Ended with Info
2. Note its MRN Number
3. Note FIN Transaction Number
4. Note QC Number against the MRN
5. Navigate to **FinTransactionReversal** Process
6. Click **New**
7. Enter Reference Document number
8. Navigate to **finTransactionReversal** Process and hit **Submit**
9. Navigate to **Unpost** process
10. Select **MRN Header** as option and enter your MRN Number
11. Click Submit
12. Navigate to **MRN Header** Process and confirm if FIN transaction number has been removed
13. Navigate to **QC Document** and search and select your MRN
14. Click **Edit** and then click **Delete**
15. Navigate to **Stock transaction transfer header**
16. Enter QC Number in **No.** and then click **Delete**
17. Navigate to **MRN Header**
18. Search your MRN and **Delete**

Re-enter your documents and run Period closure. This should resolve your error.